# Offensive words - English and Spanish

Tags: data-request, language, nlp, dictionary

Have a system generating four letter code and in testing just got up to `AA-BJ` ... and the BJ got me thinking.

In a while the one after `AR-SD` could cause offence in the UK!

Does anyone know of a list of swear words/unacceptable words anywhere? Have been looking for 20 mins without any joy.

If not will set up a little project as a resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a list of all the offensive words banned from Google's "What Do You Love?" site:
https://gist.github.com/jamiew/1112488

Wiktionary has a pretty thorough list of English Euphemisms:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_euphemisms

Wiktionary also has a (seemingly) scarce list of Spanish Euphemisms:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Spanish_euphemisms

You touched on this, but its important to clarify that certain English words are/aren't offensive, depending on where you are.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. Surprisingly short so I can hand craft my own version. The Spanish list did not look brilliant. I think I will enlist my 16 year old step-daughter who has just spent 9 months in Barcelona - if her mother agrees.

Comment: Just holding out for a Spanish - ah well. Think I will tweak the whole system to avoid the problem! Thanks for the steer.

Answer (score 1):

### Some other English & machine readable Offensive Word Lists:

---

From **abbo** to **zipperhead**

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~biglou/resources/bad-words.txt

---

Google provides an API for checking a word:

```
http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=fuck
```

gives

```
{"response": "true"}
```

---

Shuttershock has word lists for filtering:

https://github.com/shutterstock/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words

- [English](https://github.com/shutterstock/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/blob/master/en)
- [Spanish](https://github.com/shutterstock/List-of-Dirty-Naughty-Obscene-and-Otherwise-Bad-Words/blob/master/es)

---

[Bad words](http://urbanoalvarez.es/blog/2008/04/04/bad-words-list/), in TXT and SQL formats

---

([source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24515/2327328))